# Dial bootstrap nodes with devp2p(js)

Tags: go-ethereum, network, devp2p

I'm trying to use devp2p `dpt.bootstrap` to connect to Ethereum bootstrap nodes
my dpt config is like this:

```
  const dpt = new DPT(PRIVATE_KEY, {
    timeout: 10000,
    endpoint: {
      address: '0.0.0.0',
      udpPort: null,
      tcpPort: 30303,
    },
  });
```

when I run my code I got timeout error like this:

```
DPT error: Error: Invalid type: 5
DPT error: Error: Timeout error: ping 212.102.36.229:30011
DPT error: Error: Timeout error: ping 209.52.25.35:30404
DPT error: Error: Peer is banned
DPT error: Error: Peer is banned
DPT error: Error: Peer is banned
DPT error: Error: Timeout error: ping 5867:8531:b41f:9b37:ea57:e9e0:778d:9fe:30311
DPT error: Error: Timeout error: ping 5867:8531:b41f:9b37:ea57:e9e0:778d:9fe:45829
```

what should I do?